# Set variable in angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the `angular ui-bootstrap popover` and I have create a new directive to pass it along a custom template. I'm having a problem setting a variable in that template and I can't figure out the scope in which the template is rendered. Is there a way to set the template variable from within the directive? Or somehow access a variable from the parent controller?
Here is my code:

**Directive**

```
app.directive('hoverPopover', function ($compile, $templateCache, $timeout, $rootScope) {
var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
    //template = $templateCache.get('popoverTemplate.html');
    return $templateCache.get('popoverTemplate.html');
};
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = "something here";
        var content = getTemplate();
        $rootScope.insidePopover = false;
        $(element).popover({
            content: content,
            placement: 'top',
            html: true
        });
        $(element).bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                    $(element).popover('show');
                    scope.attachEvents(element);
                }
            }, 200);
        });
        $(element).bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover)
                    $(element).popover('hide');
            }, 400);
        });
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.title = "something here";
        $scope.attachEvents = function (element) {
            $('.popover').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = true;
            });
            $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = false;
                $(element).popover('hide');
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

**Template in my index.cshtml file**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popoverTemplate.html">
        <div id="angularTemplate">
            This is the content of the template
            <p>Added a paragraph here</p>
            {{title}}<br />
            <button>Button</button>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Please don't ask for a fiddle because I can't seem to get one working, and my directive doesn't work. But if you still want the full picture here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/y7az9/5/

Comment: Your code simply has too many issues. Why are you not using http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##popovers ?

Comment: Because I am already using angular-ui for other things and I wanted to stick with it. So, my question stands, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you using `angular-ui` when you're directly calling `$(element).popover({`? What you need to do is see how the `angular-ui` `popover` directive works: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.js

Comment: I'm using `angular-ui` for other things in my project. Either way, the question isn't about this, it's about how can I pass a value to title and make it render something on the page and not just `{{title}}`. So, any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Let me rephrase: If you are using `angular-ui`, why are you not using a modified version of it's `popover` directive? Why try and reinvent the wheel when all you have to do is copy-paste the source and replace the `template` property?

Comment: Hm. Good point. I didn't thought of that. I'll just alter it's template. Thanks.